# Почему выводятся оба значения в IF !empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал дополнительное поле в Wordpress через плагин ACF. В archive.php темы вывожу H1 заголовок для меток с помощью такого кода:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php $cat_page_title = the_field('h1_caption', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
       if (!empty($cat_page_title)) {
       echo $cat_page_title;
        } else 
      {                                                                    
      the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
        }
            ?></h1>
```

Но так выводятся оба заголовка: и $cat_page_title, если он заполнен, и обычный the_archive_title. Если дополнительное поле не заполнено, то соответственно выводится только обычный заголовок метки. Как убрать обычный заголовок, если дополнительное поле заполнено и оставить обычный заголовок, если оно пустое?

Comment: Этот код два заголовка одновременно выводить не может. Смотрите в чем отличие этого кода и реального

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `the_` функции вордпресса **выводят** полученные данные. А получают данные - `get_` функции.

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php $cat_page_title = get_field('h1_caption', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
                                            // ^ - `get`, не `the`
if (!empty($cat_page_title)) {
    echo $cat_page_title;
} else  {                                                                    
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
}?></h1>
```

[Мануал](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/), в который можно и заглянуть.